# Hyperledger private data collection and confidentiality

Tags: collections, hyperledger-fabric, private, confidentiality

I’m new to Hyperledger fabric and I want have some data confidential in my blockchain..
In fact I read about private data collection provided by HL , and I read that the private data is shared only among authorized peers and saved in peer’s private state database using couchDB.

**My question is,** is PDC is a good alternative for protecting data? I mean is the peers private state could be accessible by any unauthorized peer on the network?
If yes, how? And how i can protect my data without using any form of encryption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the Hyperledger community!

[Private data collections](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/private_data_tutorial.html) are ideal if you have several participants on the network that should not see the whole state of each other. Only authorized peers can access that information, if all peers follow the protocol (in particular, Fabric's private data collection definition, namely its policy). However, since a peer could deviate from the expected behavior, in theory, it could send the private data via an off-chain channel.

If you trust the network, private data is enough for your requirements. If you suspect some of the peers might misbehave (typically this is against a Fabric's network security assumptions), then encrypting data could be a good option.

Comment: Thank you Rafael, well I heve another question I mean, where is the private data is maintained? 
Assuming I have A,B ,C organization where A and B are sharing private data , it said in the documentation that the private data is stored at each authorized peer side DB  couchDB, I know for the public state if we use couchdb that mean the data is accessible through Couchdb url, hence is it the same for the sidedb? Well the private data be available through URL for other peers??

Comment: Yes, it will, if you have neither set an username/password for CouchDB nor restricted the external access to its IP/port. But each organization should have done such things (at least the second one) in a decent deployment.

Comment: Private data is saved on a local database of each peer, as @kekomal suggested, to build the so called world state. What stays on the blockchain a hash of the private data, for accountability and verifiability. This way, peers can send private data to each other in a verifiable manner, without the orderer having to read it.

Comment: Thank you Rafael and @kekomal. 
So I dont need to encrypt private data if I set a CouchDB password